# Fresh 20.04 install on MacBook Pro 2009, no wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, macbook-pro

I am attempting to install a dual boot Ubuntu on my mid 2009 15" Macbook Pro running El Capitan. It ran from my USB and did not detect my WiFi card. Here is the card info from the system report. Where can I find appropriate drivers or is my hardware just too old?

AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x8D)

Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.30)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I will give it a shot. I don't see my card on the list, but I will pull the ID from the system file.